# Setting up Yesod on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: yesod, ubuntu-13.10, cabal-dev

After following the instructions on the [QuickStart](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), I'm seeing some errors in Yesod when bringing up a webpage.  The errors end in:

> ...
>
> cannot satisfy -package-id wai-extra-1.3.4.6-62543d69d10941dae1d9b206c3eb3067:
>
> ```
> wai-extra-1.3.4.6-62543d69d10941dae1d9b206c3eb3067 is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies:
>   blaze-builder-conduit-1.0.0-1053545317cd68e3d51439dd9a0e622d zlib-conduit-1.0.0-b51dc7daf506ea4c5ecd031c5101d96a
> (use -v for more information)
> ```
>
> Build failure, pausing...

Hopefully related, the referenced [tutorial](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/) has me run

> cabal-dev install

on a fresh Yesod project, however that also gives me errors:

> ...
>
> [1 of 1] Compiling Control.Monad.Logger ( Control/Monad/Logger.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Logger.o )
>
> Control/Monad/Logger.hs:63:39:
>       Module `System.Log.FastLogger' does not export`pushLogStr'
>
> Control/Monad/Logger.hs:63:72:
>       Module `System.Log.FastLogger' does not export`LoggerSet'
>
> Control/Monad/Logger.hs:63:83:
>       Module `System.Log.FastLogger' does not export`newLoggerSet'
>
> Control/Monad/Logger.hs:63:97:
>       Module `System.Log.FastLogger' does not export`defaultBufSize'
>   Failed to install monad-logger-0.3.3.0
>
> ...

On this later set of errors, I came across a page suggesting the issue has been fixed (SO won't let me post more than 2 links, but Google the error and it comes right up).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using `cabal sandbox` for each Yesod project, rather than installing the Yesod platform as part of your system libraries. Think of a cabal sandbox as a **localized** collection of Haskell packages in a single project, so you could have different versions of a package, say `Data.Text`, in 2 different cabal sandboxes. Using `cabal sandbox` takes longer time for compilation but it makes things simpler for dependency resolution (read more here: (read more here: http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html). `cabal sandbox` requires a `cabal` version of at least 1.18 if I'm not mistaken.

Alright, enough of the talk. Let's get started.

To get the latest `cabal`, it's easier if you have `cabal` installed through a package manager, even if the package manager installs a `cabal` without `cabal sandbox`. Since you are on Ubuntu, just:

```
sudo apt-get install cabal
```

Once you have some version of `cabal` installed, run:

```
cabal sandbox
```

If you see something along the lines of this:

```
cabal: Please specify a subcommand (see 'help sandbox')
```

Then congratulations, the version of `cabal` that you have supports `cabal sandbox`, just move on **Once you have a Cabal with cabal sandbox** section of the answer.

If instead you see something like:

```
cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)
```

Then you will need a more modern version of cabal. Simply clone the [cabal repository on github](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/):

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/cabal.git
```

Go to the directory, and checkout the branch `Cabal-v1.18.1.2`, like so:

```
git checkout Cabal-v1.18.1.2
```

Then execute:

```
cabal install Cabal/ cabal-install/
```

This should install `cabal` in the `$HOME/.cabal/bin` folder. Be sure to **prepend** `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable, before the folder where the system's `cabal` is located.

### Once you have a Cabal with cabal sandbox

Based on what I read from the [Yesod quick start guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), you will want to install the `yesod-bin` package. It's hackage page is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-bin). Basically, `yesod-bin` provides you with a `yesod` binary that allows you to initialize a scaffolded site. The latest version of `yesod-bin` is 1.2.5.6, and that's what we're going to install.

Create a directory named `yesod-bin`:

```
mkdir yesod-bin
```

Go into that directory, and set up a cabal sandbox in that it, like so:

```
cabal sandbox init
```

Fetch the latest package list from hackage using:

```
cabal update
```

Now, we are going to install the latest version of `yesod-bin`, 1.2.5.6, in a cabal sandbox. However, `yesod-bin` has a dependency on the `mmorph` package, which defaults to install version 1.01, and trying to install `mmorph-1.01` will result in an error message like the following:

```
src/Control/Monad/Morph.hs:76:8:
    Could not find module `Control.Applicative.Backwards'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install mmorph-1.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
mmorph-1.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

and installing `yesod-bin` without specifiy the `mmorph` package version defaults to installing `mmorph-1.0.1`, resulting in the following error:

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
base64-conduit-1.0.0 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
blaze-builder-conduit-1.0.0 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
conduit-1.0.10 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
http-client-conduit-0.2.0.1 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
http-conduit-2.0.0.3 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
http-reverse-proxy-0.3.0 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
mmorph-1.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
network-conduit-1.0.1 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
project-template-0.1.3.2 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
resourcet-0.4.10 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
wai-2.0.0 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
wai-logger-2.1.1 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
warp-2.0.2 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
yaml-0.8.5.3 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
yesod-bin-1.2.5.6 depends on mmorph-1.0.1 which failed to install.
```

which seems to be related to these 2 issues in the `mmorph` github repo:

- https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-MMorph-Library/issues/8
- https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-MMorph-Library/pull/10

However, `mmorph` version **1.0.0** works fine. As such, we will have to specify the version of `mmorph` to be **1.0.0** when we install `yesod-bin`, like this:

```
cabal install mmorph-1.0.0 yesod-bin-1.2.5.6
```

This will take quite some time. `cabal sandbox` creates a directory named `.cabal-sandbox` inside the `yesod-bin` directory, and the `yesod` binary (along with several other binaries from the `yesod-bin` package) can be found in the `.cabal-sandbox/bin` folder. Simply add that folder into your `PATH`, and you should be able to do the `yesod init` and `yesod devel` as seen at the end of the quick start.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back.  The (very thorough and easy-to-follow) instructions worked great!  Thank you so much for helping me through the setup.

Comment: @MichaelBuchoff no problem =) I faced the same difficulty in setting up Yesod when I was getting started with it, so I can understand where people new to Yesod are coming from and made the answer as clear as I could

Answer (score 1):

As an quick update to @yanhan great answer, since I have tried to follow his guidelines on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and get stuck a bit.

If you don't have cabal executable preinstalled, you can also do:

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/cabal.git
```

Then of course:

```
git checkout Cabal-v1.20.0.2
```

And then you can use the *bootstrap.sh* script to install cabal executable and Cabal package:

```
cd cabal-install && ./bootstrap.sh
```

It will take some time, but soon after you can check the version of newly installed cabal executable:

```
$HOME/.cabal/bin/cabal --version
```